# Configuring SSIS project using config file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I am trying to follow instructions in this GitHub project to extract some data.

https://github.com/rohitsies/GNAF-SSIS-Data-Loader

It has 8 steps and I completed 7. The last one says

"To configure, ssisconfig.dtsConfig is available in the package, just change the connection string, run the package file, add the configuration path and execute."

How do I point this to a local sqlserver database?

Local server database name is ADDRESSES

Here is the configfile

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration>
    <DTSConfigurationHeading>
        <DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="DESKTOP-MOLKJJ1\Rohit" GeneratedFromPackageName="BulkLoadData" GeneratedFromPackageID="{D60E622A-F52D-4C6D-9E66-286319027A0B}" GeneratedDate="18/04/2016 11:38:10 PM" />
    </DTSConfigurationHeading>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[add_fk_constraints.sql].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>
        F:\Rohit\Work\GitProjects\Resources\FEB16_GNAF_PipeSeparatedValue_20160222170142\G-NAF\Extras\GNAF_TableCreation_Scripts\add_fk_constraints.sql
        </ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[create_tables_sqlserver.sql].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>
                F:\Rohit\Work\GitProjects\Resources\FEB16_GNAF_PipeSeparatedValue_20160222170142\G-NAF\Extras\GNAF_TableCreation_Scripts\create_tables_sqlserver.sql</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[Flat File Connection Manager].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue></ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[LocalHost.gnaf].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=gnaf;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[LocalHost.gnaf 1].Properties[ConnectionString]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=gnaf;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package\Sequence Container\Foreach Loop Container 1.ForEachEnumerator.Properties[Directory]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>F:\Rohit\Work\GitProjects\Resources\FEB16_GNAF_PipeSeparatedValue_20160222170142\G-NAF\G-NAF FEBRUARY 2016\Standard</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
    <Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package\Sequence Container 1\Foreach Loop Container.ForEachEnumerator.Properties[Directory]" ValueType="String">
        <ConfiguredValue>F:\Rohit\Work\GitProjects\Resources\FEB16_GNAF_PipeSeparatedValue_20160222170142\G-NAF\G-NAF FEBRUARY 2016\Authority Code</ConfiguredValue>
    </Configuration>
</DTSConfiguration>
```

How should I modify this? I have absolutely no clue :(

I am so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the changes in below tag

```
<ConfiguredValue>
           Data Source=.;
           Initial Catalog=gnaf;
           Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;
           Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto 
           Translate=False;
</ConfiguredValue>
```

As per the details you shared its currently pointing to the local connection.

Comment: Thanks so much. How does it know what database to put the data into? the name of my database is Addresses

Comment: Inital Catalog represents database name. you can remove gnaf and update with Adressess

Comment: Thank you so much!